# Creating SSH server on Windows for Mercurial

Tags: windows, ssh, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm struggling to find an answer for this, although it seems like such a common thing. Perhaps I'm approaching it from the wrong angle.

I would like to set up an SSH server so people can clone and push to a repository on a Windows machine. I.e.

`hg clone ssh://bob@MY_COMPUTER/C:\repository`

I've installed Bitvise SSH Server and have it set up and running and I am using TortoiseHG to manage the repository. I can connect via SSH to this computer: `ssh bob@MY_COMPUTER`. However, Mercurial seems unable to find the repository.

What am I missing? Do I need to set TortoiseHG up to start publishing the repository somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully `hg help url` and eliminate **all** Windows-isms from URL

> - path is relative to the remote user's home directory by default. Use an
>      extra slash at the start of a path to specify an absolute path:
>
>   ssh://example.com//tmp/repository

I *suppose*, for Win-hosts absolute path will start from the root of drive with $HOME of connected user, but relative path is more predictable solution